# странное поведение ссылки в Visual Studio

Tags: c++, функции, ссылки

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int& sum(int a, int b)
{
    int c = a + b;
    return c;
}
int main()
{ 
    int &rezult = sum(4, 3);
    int* pointRezult = &rezult;
    cout << rezult << " " << &rezult << endl;
    *pointRezult = 3;
    cout << rezult << " " << &rezult <<endl;
    rezult = 5;
    cout << rezult <<" " << &rezult;
    return 0;
}
```

Каламбур в том, что это работает. И главный вопрос: почему?
`rezult` ссылается на память, которая вне его доступа, ведь переменная `c` из `sum` уничтожилась.

IDE: Visual Studio 2019 в стоке.

Comment: Вы всегда, переходя на красный свет через дорогу, погибаете? Даже если дорога пустая? Вас не удивляет, что вы остаетесь живы? Вот так и тут - если выполняете правила - это какая-то гарантия что все будет работать правильно, а если нет - то может быть и так, и эдак. Undefined behavior...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Неопределенное поведение может реализовываться произвольным образом, в том числе и тем, при котором программа ведет себя так, как ожидает программист.

Если бы ссылка `int &rezult = sum(4, 3);` была константной, а функция возвращала по значению (из комментариев, спасибо), этот код был бы правильным (но вылезла бы ошибка при попытке сделать присваивание) - работало бы [правило продления времени жизни временного объекта константной ссылкой](https://habr.com/ru/post/186790/).

Comment: Нет, время жизни не продлялось бы. Чтобы это сработало, функция должна возвращать по значению.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ссылкой не поделитесь, чтобы все было аргументированно?

Comment: Извольте: [тык](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary). Начиная со слов "temporary bound to a return value", и еще со слов "lifetime of a temporary cannot be further extended".